# Migration Group Not showing in UI

Tags: 8, migrations

I am trying to migrate users table from drupal 7 to drupal 8 for that i have created custom migration module and create two file in config/install folder with the following names

> custom_migration.migration_group.open.yml
>
> custom_migration.migration.custom_user.yml

and **User.php** in `Plugin/migrate/source` for mapping fields.

The following showing content for `custom_migration.migration_group.open.yml`

```
id: open
label: Open Migration
description: Custom Migration user table form drupal 7 to drupal 8.
source_type: Drupal 7
source:
  key: drupal_7
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - custom_migration
```

Following Content is from `custom_migration.migration.custom_user.yml`

```
id: custom_user
label: Custom user migration
migration_group: open
source:
 plugin: custom_user
destination:
 plugin: entity:user
process:
 uid: uid
 name: name
 pass: pass
 mail: mail
 status: status
 created: created
 changed: changed
 access: access
 login: login
 timezone: timezone
 langcode: language
 preferred_langcode: language
 preferred_admin_langcode: language
```

When i enable the module it should show migration group in `Structure->Migration` . But it is not showing. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filenames are wrong - they need to be migrate_plus.migration.*, not custom_migration.migration.*. The first component of a configuration entity filename is the module that defines the entity *type*, not the module defining the entity *instance*.